# .htaccess Redirect Change URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

I wish to redirect `example.com/foo/[some string]FOOBAR` to `subdomain.example.com/[some string]Foobar`

I'm using in my .htaccess file 
    `RedirectMatch 301 /foo/(^.*$)FOOBAR http://subdomain.example.com/$1Foobar`
which doesn't work, just results in a 404

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably this is because you have the following rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /foo/(^.*$)FOOBAR http://subdomain.example.com/$1Foobar
```

where, you've put the `$` inside the parenthesis! Try the following one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /foo/(^.*)FOOBAR$ http://subdomain.example.com/$1Foobar
```